# Moving average filter for estimating the seasonal component

Tags: time-series, seasonality, trend, moving-average

I am reading the Introduction to Time Series and Forecasting Peter J. Brockwell • Richard A. Davis (Third Edition). I am having problems for understanding the estimation of seasonal component using the moving average.

In section 1.5.2.1 Method S1: Estimation of Trend and Seasonal Components

The authors explains

> Sample: [image: formula].

> We first estimate the trend by applying a Moving Average Filter (MAF) chosen specially to eliminate seasonality and to dampen the noise. If the period d
> is even, i.e. [image: formula], then [image: formula] If period is odd, then use the simple [image: formula].

> The second step is to estimate the seasonal component. For each  [image: formula] we compute the average $w_{k}$ of the deviations [image: formula] Since these average deviations do not necessarily sum to zero, we estimate the seasonal component [image: formula] as [image: formula]

> and [image: formula]

My question is how I estimate $w_{k}$? I am not able to understand math notation in the two last paragraphs. What does $j$ represent in the equation?

Comment: The math expressions seem to have some typos, such as the `+ +` in the expression for m-hat-sub-t. Are these copied from a digital book?

Comment: If you have monthly data, w_1 will be the average deviation in the month of January between the real value and the value that the Moving Average Filter takes in that month.

Comment: @PedroSchuller If I take the average between the deviation and the real value I will have a vector with `k` observations so how do i get my original length series? which is a vector with `n` observations

Comment: Indeed! Afterwards, the seasonal component will be repeated as many times as the number of periods. If you have 5 years of data, the seasonal component for, say, January 2015, '16, '17, '18 and '19 will be the same.

Comment: Have you figured it out, or do you still have a question?

Comment: no, i can not figure out.

Comment: Sorry, did not see you comment. When responding to a particular user, add @name (in my case, name=RichardHardy), as otherwise the user does not get notified.

Answer (score 0):

$j$ is an integer that takes values restricted by $q<k+jd\leq n-q$. In other words, $j$ takes all integer values that satisfy the inequality $\frac{q-k}{d}<j<\frac{n-q-k}{d}$.

As Pedro Schuller correctly said, *if you have monthly data, $w_1$ will be the average deviation in the month of January between the real value and the value that the Moving Average Filter takes in that month*. $w_2$ will be the corresponding value for February, and so on.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, I am not able to see how the filter works. For example, if `k=1...,7` my vector `S_k` will be `[1, 7]`, but in the last line the authors say that `k<d` and after that they say that the deseasonalized data is `d_t = x_t - s_t` with `t=1,....n`. Sorry if my question is too obvious, maybe can you recommend another book or paper which explains the details behind the  filter?

Comment: Book: Business Forecasting by John Hanke & Arthur Reich

Comment: Forecasting: Principles and Practice by Rob J Hyndman and George Athanasopoulos: https://otexts.com/fpp2/